# In minor, can the neapolitan sixth chord resolve to the diminished seventh chord on the leading-tone (of the same key)?

Tags: chord-progressions, voice-leading

What would that look like voice-leading-wise? I'm assuming more or less traditional common-practice harmony rules. Examples from the literature would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My hunch is that, if a ♭II6 did resolve to vii°7, it would tend to resolve to one in second inversion (that is, vii°43). This way, the bass scale-degree 4 stays constant. This is one reason why ♭II6 resolving to V42 is so common.

I know of two examples in the literature where ♭II resolves to vii°7. First, and I think most in line with what you're looking for, is from the opening measures of Saint-Saëns' "Organ" Symphony. Here, the ♭II6 resolves to vii°65:

[image]

Another example to consider is from Weber's Overture to *Der Freischütz*.

[image]

There are a few things to notice here:

1. The Neapolitan (mm. 4–5) is in second inversion (!).
2. It resolves to a vii°7 chord in *third* inversion (m. 6).
3. But most importantly, that vii°42 really just delays the appearance of V7 on the downbeat of the last measure. In other words, I view the A♭ in the next-to-last measure as a suspension from the ♭II64. As such, I hesitate to call that measure a vii°42; in my opinion, the final two measures are V7, we just have a long suspension in the bass.

More common, as you probably already know, is for the Neapolitan to resolve to an applied diminished-seventh chord *of the dominant*. As one example of many, consider this quick example from the last movement of Mahler 2:

[image]

The Neapolitan is on the third beat of the first measure, and it moves through vii°7/V on beat 4.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent and well-documented answer!

Comment: Where do you get your music examples from, if I may ask? Some sort of database?

Comment: @KimFierens The database of a theory professor's brain :-)

Comment: Yes, I sort of guessed that you knew the music itself from memory. But what I was wondering was how you got the notation so ready at hand. Or are you just a rapid typist in Finale/Sibelius/whatever?

Comment: @KimFierens Oh, I see! I make these examples in a program called LilyPond, which I think is much faster (once you learn it) than Finale or Sibelius.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely look into this LllyPond program, because in Finale it takes "forever" to create even rather simple and brief examples.

Comment: @KimFierens Full disclosure: LilyPond has a pretty steep learning curve. I strongly recommend the video tutorials at https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHi8BvxILUV6x9FqEmZiYrEj6VMGmTKjt, which I used when I first learned.